# How to return http error responses based on request accept media type in flask

Tags: python, flask

Is there a way in flask to return each http error response in the format of the request accept media type?

For example, by default the http error responses are returned as html. I would like to have these returned as json if the request accept media type is 'application/json'.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you use the Accept header for this (see http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/45/). You did't say how these HTTP error responses are being generated, but you should check the Accept header when the error is being triggered and format the response based on that. There isn't any magic that will automatically render the error response in another format.

Comment: I'm thinking of the http error responses that are triggered automatically by flask.

Comment: Do you mean 404 and 500, which you didn't call abort()? If so, you can use app.errorhandler (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/errorpages/). Otherwise, can you post an example of an error you're referring to?

Comment: Are those the only http error responses triggered automatically by flask? Are there other http responses that are not errors that are triggered automatically by flask that I should convert as well?

Comment: You would want to handle any that you trigger with abort() as well.

Comment: So the only http responses that are not generated explicitly by a call that I make are 404 and 500?

Comment: If I use curl to send an invalid parameter it appears to automatically respond with a 400 response.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot that one.